# Abstract data types

Tags: haskell, matrix, abstract-data-type

I am trying to understand abstract data types. In the code below I am supposed to write a function for an abstract data type. `createMatrix` takes in a tuple of the number of x rows and y columns and some element z and fills in the matrix with that element.

I am new to Haskell and am okay with all the basics, but am extremely confused on how to implement this function for an abstract data type.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to do this.

Many thanks in advance!

```
newType Matrix a = Mat ((Int, Int), (Int,Int) -> a)


createMatrix (x,y) z =
```

Comment: I do not see anything abstract about the `Matrix` datatype.

Comment: It's unfortunate that “Abstract Data Type” and “Algebraic Data Type” have the same initials.

Comment: [Abstract Data Types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) and [Algebraic Data Types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) mean something quite different.

Comment: I *do* see something abstract about `Matrix`.  It is abstract to anybody who doesn't use the `Mat` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got as far as

```
createMatrix (x,y) z = {-TODO-}
```

The obvious next step is

```
createMatrix (x,y) z = Mat ( {-TODO-} , {-TODO-} )
```

Why should this be obvious?

- Your function gives back a value of type `Matrix a`; this has only one constructor, `Mat`: so that is what that value must start with.
- The `Mat` constructor take a single value, a pair. We don't have a pair of the correct type to hand, so we will have to make one. Again, there is only a single constructor, `( , )`, so that's what we use.

Importantly, I have done this just by following the types (and assuming you don't have any helper functions ready to call).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I am still not sure what then next step should be at this point. Doesn't Mat constructor take in two pairs? can you give me some intuition as to what `TODO` should be? is it just a function that helps create the Matrix?

Comment: The `Mat` constructor takes a single pair: `((Int, Int), (Int,Int) -> a)`. The first element of this pair is itself a pair: `(Int, Int)` (which looks similar to one of `createMatrix`'s parameters); and the second element is a function: `(Int,Int) -> a`.

Comment: Presumably you have been told what the values in the `Mat` constructor mean?

Comment: I have not been told anything about the values of the Mat constructor (other than that mentioned in the original post above). All I know is I am supposed to write a function `createMatrix` for type Matrix which is an abstract data type.

Comment: @MiGusta It would make sense if the values are the size of the matrix and a function taking an index and returning the corresponding value. [`const`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:const) might be useful for you.